# Do Max/MSP support TCP sockets?

Tags: sockets, flash, tcp, max, msp

Do Max/MSP support TCP sockets? How to receive signals sent from Flash (actionscript 2) XML Socket into Max/Msp? I've read about net.tcp recv and flashserver but they don't seem to be supported anymore.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Max doesn't have objects supporting TCP, except Java class net.tcp.recv. Note, that this class should be used with **mxj** object: **[mxj net.tcp.recv]**. You can find the source code of this object in the `$maxdir$/C74/java-classes/classes/net/tcp/` directory.

In fact, nothing stops you from writing your own Java class for handling TCP. You can start from reading tutorial which bundled with Max: `$maxdir$/C74/java-doc/WritingMaxExternalsInJava.pdf`. Please note, you should compile Java using Java 6 language, not higher.

Answer (score 0):

Max has udp send and udp receieve objects, over which you can send OSC messages. [flosc](http://benchun.net/projects/flosc/) seems to be a good tool to send receive OSC between Max and Flash.

> flosc is a Java server that can communicate with anything that
>   uses the OpenSound Control protocol. It can also communicate with
>   Macromedia Flash (versions 5 and later) using Flash’s XMLSocket
>   feature. flosc acts as a gateway between OSC and Flash...